# Unable to locate the model you have specified: gbyte_user_admin

Tags: php, codeigniter

I seem not actually figure out what this problem is. In my application where the error is pointing to is a folder **gbyte_user_admin** so tracing down the error is much more challenging to me as I am new to CodeIgniter.
This is a snapshot of the content in the folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e76dX.png)

Please does anyone know how I can trace down this error or what may be causing this error

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html is your model in the application/models also make sure you follow this way of naming classes and filenames https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

If this is error in model gbyte_user_admin then you should look for error in file "application/models/gbyte_user_admin.php". The directory shown on screen is "system" which contain only framework files which should not be modified.